# Desktop simulator component for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, extjs, components

ExtJs has a very nice way to simulate a desktop environement in a web page, here you can see 
[an example of it](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/desktop/desktop.html)

Is there an asp.net component that does anything similar?

Update:
I don't mean using asp.net as backend, but using a component in an aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Net is an asp.net library for ExtJS.  We used it at a previous employer to implement a desktop.

http://www.ext.net

Here's an example of the Desktop Implementation:

http://examples.ext.net/#/Desktop/Introduction/Overview/